# Copy MAC terminal output to my clipboard without mouse but by using shortcut from keyboard

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have the following:

[image]

After typing (*pwd*),
how can I copy my terminal output (*/sdcard/Android/data*) using my **keyboard** and not another command or my mouse?

**NOTE:** I looked online but I only found ways on how to copy the last output using another command which makes it even more tedious since using a mouse will be faster.

Comment: I’m fairly sure there isn’t a way to select the last command’s output using the keyboard, but that depends on the terminal emulator. Command-C and Command-V work as expected if you can get the output selected, though.

Comment: Command-C and Command-V works fine but you have to select the output using your mouse as you mentioned. I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut though.

Answer (score 3):

macOS contains two terminal commands dealing with the clipboard: `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` (for whatever reason they use the term `pasteboard` instead of `clipboard`). You can just pipe content into `pbcopy` or out of `pbpaste` to copy or paste from the clipboard.

To copy the current working directory, as in your example, you would write:

```
$ pwd | pbcopy
```

EDIT: okay, just saw the requirement to copy it with the keyboard, and not with another command… So ignore my answer, will probably delete it soon.

Comment: Okay, have a look at a [similar question at AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249420/is-it-possible-to-select-terminal-output-by-using-keyboard-keys) for suggestions.